# Удаление данных в firebase на android

Tags: android, firebase

Допустим есть дерево на firebase:

```
Users -
       User1 -
               Name - jack
               Age - 21
       User2 -
               Name - john
               Age - 32
```

Как удалить не конкретное значение ,  а полностью например `user1`.?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 3):

Получите ссылку на дерево:

```
 myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://somewhere.firebaseio.com/Users/");
 myFirebaseRef.child("user1").removeValue();
```

И так далее получайте ссылки на "детей", которых хотите удалить. Для этого надо еще раз вызвать child.